# Assign an agent app to all desktops

Tags: macos, dock, desktop

I am running an app ([Simple Floating Clock](http://www.splook.com/Software/Simple_Floating_Clock.html)) that runs as an agent ([LSUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-108256-TPXREF136) assigned to 1 in the app's Info.plist).

I would like to assign the app to "All Desktops" that I run.  Normally, if an app is not an agent, I can right click on the dock icon, select options, and then click "All Desktops".

Is there a simple way to set the all desktops behavior, maybe using the command line or something?

Comment: I did just notice that the app I mentioned has a menu bar icon, so it does provide an option for the functionality that I am looking for.  However, I think that the question is still a valid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the app to All Desktops, *then* set LSUIElement to 1. It should remember the change and abide by it even though it now runs as an agent.